# Spring and Jboss SAML Integration

Tags: java, spring, jboss, saml, picketlink

Is it possible to configure my spring application (which runs on tomcat) as service provider in SAML integration, where identity provider is configured on jboss 7 server? We have several subsystems, integrated via picketlink and now I am struggling to integrate my spring application with them.
I wonder if you have some examples / tutorials on how such integration can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has a SAML extentions [spring-security-saml](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml) There is also a sample included.